# Можно ли запустить bat файл относительно другого сервера?

Tags: windows, bat

Например, имеется n шар, которые принадлежат разным серверам. Могу ли я скинуть туда батник и запустить его относительно сервера, который держит эту шару? Например, передал батник на шару, запустил его и какой то процесс пошёл на самом сервере. Если нет, то какие могут быть альтернативы? Задача, запустить из одного места процессы на всех серверах. Можно ли будет получать информацию из консолей на других серверах себе в консоль? Например, запустил какой нибудь робокопи на сервере, а вся информация отсылается мне в консоль

Comment: Можно попробовать PsExec от Sysinternals. https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb897553

Answer (score 1):

Если необходим вывод консоли, то самый простой вариант - SSH или Telnet, но это потребует установки и настройки соответствующего сервера на удалённой машине. Так же можно использовать PowerShell и WS-Management протокол, но это так же потребует некоторой настройки удалённой машины.